# Removing a cron job via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cron

I'm creating a cron job in a script like this:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
crontab -l > crontask
grep "* * * * * $DIR/somescript" crontask || echo "* * * * * $DIR/somescript" >> crontask
```

I'd like to build a script that can delete this job, how should I do that?

Comment: delete what job?

Comment: The "* * * * * $DIR/somescript", is it called a cron task maybe?

Comment: `crontab -l | grep -v "\* \* \* \* \* $DIR/somescript" | crontab -`

Comment: @123 Thanks a lot!